# Django-redis configuration to use socket rather than TCP

Tags: django, redis, django-redis

I'm attempting to use django-redis [using Unix sockets rather than a TCP connection](https://django-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#usage-of-cache-backend):

This is the `settings.py` configuration:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unix:/tmp/redis.sock:1',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'PICKLE_VERSION': -1,   # default
            'PARSER_CLASS': 'redis.connection.HiredisParser',
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'redis_cache.client.DefaultClient',
        },
    },
}
```

and this is an extract of the redis config file at `/etc/redis/6379.conf`:

```
# Specify the path for the unix socket that will be used to listen for
# incoming connections. There is no default, so Redis will not listen
# on a unix socket when not specified.
#
unixsocket /tmp/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 755
```

Still I receive a `ConnectionInterrumped` exception, which stands for an error during connection. Any ideas about what this configuration's issue is?

P.S. My Django version is `1.5.1`, django-redis is `3.3` and hiredis is `0.0.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Apparently I read the cache provider wrong, the below answer is the solution for `django-redis-cache`, not `django-redis`. I'll let the answer remain though, since changing cache provider and using this config seems to have solved the problem.

You should not need the `unix:` prefix, and the backend setting looks strange;

```
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
    'LOCATION': '/tmp/redis.sock',
    'OPTIONS': { ...
```

Comment: chagning `LOCATION` to what you suggest raises an `Improperly configured` exception with message `Incorrect format '/tmp/redis.sock'`. Also, the location of `RedisCache` class is correct (I looked at the sources).

Comment: @JosvicZammit Odd, may be a version difference then, [this page](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache) seems to agree with me.

Comment: The problem is this: I'm using [`django-redis`](https://django-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and not [`django-redis-cache`](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache). I switched to `django-redis-cache`, and now things work as prescribed. Please edit your answer to point out that not [`django-redis-cache`](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache) is being used and let me know so that I mark it as correct. Thanks!